# ImportError: Package installed from Git using pip not found by Python

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, installation, pip

I'm trying to use pip to install a package from a remote Git repo. The install seems to work fine:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/<me>/<mypackage>.git
...
Installing collected packages: <mypackage>
    Running setup.py install for <mypackage> ... done
Successfully installed <mypackage>-1.0.0.dev1
$ pip freeze | grep <mypackage>
<mypackage>==1.0.0.dev1
ls ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages | grep <mypackage>
<mypackage>-1.0.0.dev1-py2.7.egg-info
```

But the package import fails:

```
$ python
>>> import <mypackage>
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named <mypackage>
>>>
```

I've been able to successfully install and import it from a local version:

```
$ pip install -e <path-to-mypackage>
```

but I'd like to be able to install it through git.

Under what conditions can a package (apparently) successfully pip install, but not be imported by Python?

The structure of my module is:

```
<mypackage>
    setup.py
    <mypackage>
        __init__.py
        # some files
```

I'm running OS X 10.11.6 and a brew-installed version of Python 2.7.13 and pip.

Comment: does `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mypackage/` exists? I guess your setup.py missed some package definition.

Comment: can you provide the output of `which python`, `which pip` and `pip --version`?

Comment: `which python` outputs `/usr/local/bin/python`, `which pip` outputs `/usr/local/bin/pip` and `pip --version` outputs `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`.

Answer (score 4):

The repository cloned by you is not a python package.It is rather a folder containing the package.

To import the package simply cd into the inner my `<mypackage>` folder and then try to import it. But it's not a good idea, rather you may run the setup.py file contained in the outer `<mypackage>`folder to set up everything for you.This will also (usually) add the package to the environment variable so that you can import it from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. After running `pip install $PATH-TO-PACKAGE` I'm able to successfully import the package. But I'd like to be able to install it on other machines by installing from the git repository, rather than from a local directory. I've edited my question so hopefully this is clearer now.

Comment: did you solve it? I am having exactly the same problem